# Is the only time a monster encounter occurs during the movement phase or when 'a monster appears'?

Tags: arkham-horror

Do monster encounters only occur during the movement phase when leaving a space with a monster or ending at one, and also when cards say a monster appears? Flying monsters moving to your space don't induce an encounter right?

Comment: Flying monsters aren't any different from other monsters in this regard. It affects how they move, not when you fight them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you start your movement phase on a location or Street with any monsters,  you must either evade them all or fight them.

If you attempt to pass through a location or street with a monster on it,  you must either evade or fight them.

If you end your movement on a location or street with a monster,  you must either evade or fight them.

Flying monsters usually move during the mythos phase,  so you won't need to fight them till your next movement phase.

Monsters that appear due to encounters need to be fought or evaded immediately.

An exception to the above is when you return from an other world location and have an explored marker. On your first turn after returning,  you don't need to fight or evade any monsters guarding the gate,  giving you one relatively safe shot at closing the gate

For the exception above, you can find it in the rules on page 18

> During the turn he returns to Arkham from an Other World, an
>   investigator does not have to evade or fight any monsters in the
>   gate’s location. This rule only applies during the turn he returns to
>   Arkham; in subsequent turns, if the investigator remains in the
>   location, he must evade or fight any monsters there as normal.